# I can't get good displacement on my donut!

Tags: node-editor, displacement

I'm a noob Blender user following BlenderGuru's donut series. I'm on the part where he does displacement, but it just doesn't look as good as his. Mine isn't horrible, but its definitely not good.

What I'm Trying To Get:
[image]

My Donut Nodes:
[image]

My Donut Finish:
[image]

My Donut Mesh:
[image]

Besides the displacement part the donut is fine with me, so that's all I need fixing right now. **I have tried using a subsurface modifier**, but that made it look weirder if anything. Any help is appreciated, and I'll give more pictures as requested.

Comment: Hello :). What *exactly* aren't you happy with? "Not great, not terrible" isn't very specific :)

Comment: Two things stand out to me.  The color ramp on the bottom noise texture is probably generating the more "spiky" feel of your example.  On the top noise texture, a scale of 1500 is... quite a lot.  It may be too fine to do much to this geometry, even as dense as it is.